# Wordpress Woocommerce Tiles view possible?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

is it possible for Woocommerce/Wp to display Tiles view something like this:

http://crated.com/collections/automotive or https://squareup.com/market

any help or starting points will be great.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah that's possible. 
You just need is proper structure. And it can be done in anything whether it's WooCommerce or WordPress or any other CMS, framework

There is JS named [gridster](http://gridster.net/#demos) which can help you.